# Existence of a subset of $\Omega$ that induces a certain sub-measure of the law

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Given a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and a random variable $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, let $\mu=\mathbb{P}\circ X^{-1}$ be the law of $X$. Suppose that there is a Borel measure $\nu$ such that $\nu(A) \leq \mu(A)$ for all measurable $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

I am wondering when (i.e., what properties should $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and $X$ have) can you find a $\Omega' \subset \Omega$ so that 
$$\mathbb{P}(\Omega' \cap X^{-1}(A))=\nu(A)$$

This seems straightforward but I just can't figure out the right way to look at it.

I can get the result when $X$ is a simple function and when $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ is nonatomic, but I really want a weaker condition on $X$, ideally nothing but measurability.

Thanks!